# Converting a txt file to xls file

Tags: python, excel, type-conversion

I need some help with specifying format of values in xls. I am converting a txt file into xls.

Below is my current code. As I read the txt file, i need to put the values as Int/Float or str. Int is ok, as well str, but I can't solve a problem with floats.

`366351.77` or `-6000.00`, for example, are still being inserted as a str in the sheet.

I don't know if the problem is when i'm reading the content of the txt file or if it is when i tried to convert the string content of the txt to a float format.

```
import sys
import openpyxl

delimitador, caminho, destino = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3]
xls = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = xls.active
sheet.column_dimensions['A']
txt = open(caminho)


def is_float(s):
    result = False
    if s.count(".") == 1:
       if s.replace(".", "").isdigit():
          result = True
    return result


    i = 1
    for linha in txt:
        coluna = linha.split(delimitador)
        ii = 1
        for celula in coluna:
            cell = sheet.cell(row=i, column=ii)
            if is_float(celula):
                #cell.value = float(celula.decode('latin-1').encode('utf-8'))
                cell.value = 'float'            
            elif celula.isdigit():
                cell.value = int(celula.decode('latin-1').encode('utf-8'))
            else:
                cell.value = celula.decode('latin-1').encode('utf-8')
            ii += 1
        i += 1
   xls.save(destino)
   txt.close()
```

Comment: There's a problem here -- right now, with the indentation, you have the body of your code inside of the `is_float` function *after* its `return`. Did you test that your example really works in its cut-down-for-StackOverflow form? (See the MCVE guidelines at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- "complete" and "verifiable" both require that code provided for illustration actually function).

Comment: Tks Charles, the code is in the correct indentation on my project, just on the Stack it is wrong... i'll chek the MCVE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `set_explicit_value` method of the `cell` object.

```
cell.set_explicit_value(value=your_float, data_type='f')
```

Docs:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html#openpyxl.cell.cell.Cell.set_explicit_value

Answer (score 0):

First of all tks so much Nicarus, your help solved my problem.

Here is my final code, now The values as Number(Values, Accounts, Index..) are being correctly added as a number in the Worksheet, and the others value as (Date, Description...) are being added as String

[FinalCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E53LH.jpg)